# How to copy a file to host during packer provisioning?

Tags: packer

I would like to generate a public/private ssh key pair during packer provisioning and copy the files to the host machine. Is there a way to copy files out from the VM to the host using packer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. The file provisioner has a "direction" option that allows download instead of upload

```
{
"type": "file",
"source": "app.tar.gz",
"destination": "/tmp/app.tar.gz",
"direction" : "download"
}
```