# Using packer to copy file from host to generated image without password

Tags: shell, ssh, amazon-ec2, scp, packer

I am currently using packer to generate customized images from a given configuration. The packer `.json` file includes provisions, which are described in [this packer tutorial](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/provision.html).

Instead of typing the commands there, I used the shell option in which I can write a bunch of `sudo apt-get install` commands to customize the images.

The problem is that I need to copy a file from a computer I own to the images. To be clear, the computer I own is also the one I'm running the command `packer build example.json`.

In the shell script, how can I do a secure copy so that **from the perspective of the newly-created images**, the image can securely copy the file from my computer to itself, *without* having to type a password? This is a shell script so I couldn't type one in if I wanted to.

I understand that to avoid typing in the password, I need public/private key authentication. In the shell script, I have:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
sudo scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@example.com:/home/user/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub
sudo ssh user@example.com "echo `cat ~/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub` >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

(Taken from [the example here](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh) and elsewhere. My understanding from this is that the image which is generated is running these commands.)

The problem with this and many approaches I see on StackOverflow, such as with [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558080/scp-secure-copy-to-ec2-instance-without-password), is either one of two things.

- The *first* time this public/private authentication happens, it seems like a password is needed. However, this is done entirely in a shell script so I don't know how to avoid it.
- packer generates these images on the fly, so other approaches that require me to type in explicit AMI IDs for `ssh` or `scp` do not seem to work.

A [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511571/how-to-copy-a-file-to-host-during-packer-provisioning) uses the "file" provision type, but I would like to do this with the "shell" type and I'm not sure how to use both the file and the shell options.

How may I resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the `file` provisioner, something like:

```
"provisioners": [
  {
    "type": "file",
    "source": "source_file",
    "destination": "dest"
  },
  {
    "type": "script",
    "inline": [ "echo do something here" ]
  }
]
```

See [documentation: provisioners "file"](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/docs/provisioners/file)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize we could have an array of those, I thought I remember reading somewhere that we could have only one. Let me try those, though I'll have to figure out what exactly goes in the source/dest arguments.